# Bulk Load Conversion Error (truncation)... missing something obvious

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a table defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [ThirdPartyData].[AdsTxtFile](
    [DomainHostName] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Expires] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Advertiser] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [AdvertiserId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AdvertiserType] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [TAGId] [varchar](100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AdsTxtFile] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
        [DomainHostName] ASC,
        [Advertiser] ASC,
        [AdvertiserId] ASC
        )
)
```

I am trying to bulk insert a file into this table.  The first few lines of the file are:

```
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)google.com(TAB)pub-1301581561755234(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)f08c47fec0942fa0
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)indexexchange.com(TAB)184046(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)indexexchange.com(TAB)183430(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)indexexchange.com(TAB)184124(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)indexexchange.com(TAB)182270(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)appnexus.com(TAB)7287(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)amazon-adsystem.com(TAB)3049(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)Kargo.com(TAB)114(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)Kargo.com(TAB)115(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)openx.com(TAB)537114802(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)a698e2ec38604c6
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)rubiconproject.com(TAB)7791(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)0bfd66d529a55807
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)rubiconproject.com(TAB)15896(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)0bfd66d529a55807
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)rubiconproject.com(TAB)11636(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)0bfd66d529a55807
roadandtrack.com(TAB)9/13/2017 12:00:00 AM(TAB)teads.tv(TAB)10237(TAB)DIRECT(TAB)15a9c44f6d26cbe1
```

I have replaced the tab characters in the file with `(TAB)` for visibility in this post, but they are actual tab characters in the file itself.  Each line in the file is terminated by a newline character.

I run the following command in SQL Server:

```
BULK INSERT [ThirdPartyData].[AdsTxtFile] FROM 'MyFileLocation.txt'
```

I get an exception as follows:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 6 (TAGId).
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

...now I'm scratching my head, since my understanding is that tabs and newlines are the default terminators for the bulk insert command, and the "f08c47fec0942fa0" for `TAGId` on the first row definitely does not exceed 100 characters in length, so I don't know what the problem is.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A SSIS package would be cleaner and repeatable.

Comment: Our business leaders have threatened violence if we bring SSIS into our systems.  It's a source of endless... "discussion", shall we say.

Comment: Do your lines end \r or \r\n? Try explicitly setting ROWTERMINATOR

Comment: my lines are set to \n.  I'll try messing with that

Comment: Yup, changed the line ends to \r\n and it started working.  The documentation suggested the default was \n, looks like that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the documentation I read suggested that the default row termination was a newline, or linefeed character (\n)... but that does not seem to be the case.  Once I changed my line endings to carriage-return linefeed (\r\n) it worked.